# MySQL: Why not create an index on every column? What is the cost of indexing a column?

Tags: mysql, php

I *know* I shouldn't have an index on every column, but I don't know WHY.  What is the cost?

I have a system with about 400 tables, many of which have datetimes or foreign keys (which might not ACTUALLY have foreign key rules, since they're not strict) which lack indexes.  This can cause a massive query time on a relatively simple query (ex: 3 columns across 3 tables with a time condition and a table's primary key).

The time to run the query in question took me over 2 minutes, but once I added indexes on the timestamp and the foreign key it dropped to under 200ms, a 6000% gain.  I am tempted to add indexes on EVERY column I have metrics on, but I know (from other people telling me) excessive indexes are bad.  But I cannot find WHY anywhere!

So my question, at the basis is: **what are "too many" indexes, and why?**

Comment: Re "too many":  My Rules of Thumb:  At most about 5 indexes on a table; at most about 5 columns in any composite `INDEX`.  Rarely two `UNIQUEs` in a table (including the PK); three is very suspicious.  (J.D. goes into a lot of good details about "why", etc.)

Comment: What, exactly, does this `(which might not ACTUALLY have foreign key rules, since they're not strict)` mean? Either you have `FOREIGN KEY`s or you don't - you can't have `"not strict"` FK-s! Normally MySQL creates an index on foreign key fields if a suitable one isn't present!

Comment: @Vérace For example I might have a phone_numbers table with a person_id which points to the people table's primary key.  But since the phone_number doesn't HAVE to be tied to a single/specific person, there is no SQL constraint despite the logical connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An index literally stores a copy of the data, sorted on the fields covered by that index (and automatically includes the clustered index key), generally in a data structure called a B-Tree.
Creating an index on every field of every table would literally triple the amount of data in your database (approximately).

Aside from the extra space requirements, it costs time to write data to a table (and specifically to disk). For every index on a table, whenever a record is inserted into the table, it's an additional write operation that has to occur to persist the data. Having too many indexes could potentially affect the overall write speed of your database and result in unneeded contention and table locking for too long.

Also indexes are optimal when they cover (are defined) on the fields that are part of the predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, or `HAVING` clauses) of your queries. For example, if you have the following predicate `WHERE Field1 = 91 AND Field2 = 13` but you define your index on `(Field3, Field1, Field2)` then your index doesn't cover your `WHERE` clause and likely won't be used or won't be performant if used to serve the data for that query, because it's unable to seek on the fields used in your query when that index is first sorted by a field not in your predicate.

The order you specify your fields in an index definition is what defines what predicates it covers because it is the order of which fields are sorted in the B-Tree. So it's important to carefully design your indexes to cover your queries as well as possible. Typically that's not by creating an index for each individual field, and generally there's too many fields to reasonably create an index for every possible combination that might be used in a predicate.

Alternatively it's better to identify your slowest, heaviest, and most commonly used queries and predicates, and then test if indexing is the solution to improving them. There's not a fixed number of indexes that works for everyone, but a general rule of thumb I like to go by as a starting point is what I call the 5 x 5 rule. The 5 x 5 rule is try to create no more than 5 indexes per table, and try not to include more than 5 columns per index definition. Of course, this is a soft rule, and there are cases where crossing those thresholds are fine.

Comment: More like 3x -- the PK is duplicated in each secondary index.

Comment: @RickJames Fair point, updated my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You won't just need an index on every column. MySQL queries generally use just one index per table, but you may have multiple terms in your conditions. So you could create multi-column indexes. If you wanted to proactively create every index you could possibly need, you would need at least 2<sup>*n*</sup> indexes for *n* columns.

But it's even worse than that. The order of columns in an index is significant. I.e. an index on columns `(a, b, c)` may be needed, but also an index on `(a, c, b)` may be needed for a different query. So you need not only every combination of columns, but potentially every *permutation* of columns. The number of indexes you would need is on the order of *n*-factorial.

At that point, the CREATE TABLE statement itself would become prohibitively large, to say nothing of the storage space it would require to keep so many indexes.

Obviously, most of these indexes are not needed, because you don't actually need to optimize an unlimited variety of queries. You only need to optimize the queries you do have in your application code.

We could make an analogy to designing methods in a PHP class (or whatever your favorite programming language is). Why not create every possible class method, with every possible set of arguments, just in case you need it? Why not create class member variables of every data type? Of course this is ridiculous. You only need to create the class methods and members you will use in that class.

I don't like to try to define a rule about how many indexes are too many. You need as many indexes as you need to optimize the queries you have. If you have too many, it will take a lot of storage space, and DML statements will become more expensive (an insert/update/delete must change entries in every index in your table).

Still, it's up to you to decide if the tradeoff is appropriate for your application. That's why you're paid as a professional software engineer, because you have the analytical skills to measure the cost-benefit ratio, and you have the judgment to decide if it's worth it in a given case.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answers: As a rule of thumb, an index is not used if  approximately 30% of the values in the field are of one value.

You can check this with

```
  select indexfield, count(*) from table group by indexfield
```

If any of the values is > 30% of rows, the index is unlikely to be used by the database unless you force it.

I believe a rough explanation would be that scanning the index would take 3 times as much time in terms of disk operations than scanning the actual table (assuming many fields of the table are returned from the query), so most modern RDMS choose to ignore such an index, correctly.

Practically this means:

- indexes on tinyint(1) cannot work
- most status fields may have 2-10 values, but often 1 or 2 values comprise 90% of records - won't be used